# Me foi passado este exercicio: "TODOS OS CLIENTES QUE COMPRARAM MAIS DE R$ 200,00 NO ÚLTIMO MÊS"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT clientes.nome,clientes.sexo,
       SUM(pedidos.valor_pedidos) AS total_gasto,clientes.cidade

FROM clientes

INNER JOIN pedidos
  ON clientes.id_clientes = pedidos.id_clientes

WHERE sexo LIKE 'F%' 
AND valor_pedidos >= 100

GROUP BY nome;
```

porem minha query não retorna o valor da soma, retorna o valor unitário. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Me parece que você está desconsiderando a restrição "no último mês".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você esqueceu de agrupar o sexo. Faltou algumas boas praticas de programação para facilitar a leitura e evitar erros, eu não gosto de utilizar as condicionais no cruzamento (Inner Join) como o sexo like 'f%' e sim no Where, recomendo esse método para evitar dores de cabeça, segue o código ajustado:

```
SELECT clientes.nome,clientes.sexo,
       SUM(pedidos.valor_pedidos) AS total_gasto,clientes.cidade
   
FROM clientes

INNER JOIN pedidos
  ON clientes.id_clientes = pedidos.id_clientes

WHERE sexo LIKE 'F%' 
AND valor_pedidos >= 100

GROUP BY clientes.nome,clientes.sexo;
```

Nesse exercício que te passaram, você irá precisar trazer o campo mês e agrupar ele, se só tiver a data você deverá realizar o MONTH() e ignorar esse AND valor_pedidos >= 100, pois você só poderá verificar esse resultado depois da soma. Particularmente eu utilizaria um subselect para trazer o resultado dessa consulta:

```
SELECT nome,sexo,mes,total_gasto

FROM(  
     
     SELECT clientes.nome,clientes.sexo,pedidos.mes
            SUM(pedidos.valor_pedidos) AS total_gasto,clientes.cidade
   
     FROM clientes

     INNER JOIN pedidos
       ON clientes.id_clientes = pedidos.id_clientes

     WHERE sexo LIKE 'F%' 

     GROUP BY clientes.nome,clientes.sexo,pedidos.mes) --SUBSELECT

WHERE total_gasto >= 200;
```

Answer (score 2):

A cláusula `HAVING` poderá ser útil para a solução de seu problema.

Supondo que exista um campo `data` em sua tabela pedidos e que "último mês" seja o mês anterior ao mês corrente tente:

```
SELECT clientes.nome, clientes.sexo, SUM(pedidos.valor_pedidos) AS total_gasto, clientes.cidade
FROM clientes
INNER JOIN pedidos ON (clientes.id_clientes = pedidos.id_clientes)
WHERE clientes.sexo LIKE 'F%'
  AND YEAR(pedidos.data) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
  AND MONTH(pedidos.data) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
GROUP BY clientes.nome, clientes.sexo, clientes.cidade 
HAVING SUM(valor_pedidos) >= 200;
```